# i am having an issue with my flutter app where app is being killed after sometime

Tags: flutter, crash

Below is one warning i gets in console no other error logs , app just gets killed automatically, system Launcher gets hanged, and sometimes mobile also gets restarted , i checked all packages i used there is no issue found, can someone suggest how do i debug this issue.below warning also doean't shows every time, 6 out of 10 time this warning appears

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Stream has been disposed.
An ImageStream is considered disposed once at least one listener has been added and subsequently all listeners have been removed and no handles are outstanding from the keepAlive method.
To resolve this error, maintain at least one listener on the stream, or create an ImageStreamCompleterHandle from the keepAlive method, or create a new stream for the image.
#0      ImageStreamCompleter._checkDisposed (package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart:607:7)
#1      ImageStreamCompleter.reportImageChunkEvent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart:747:5)
#2      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1593:10)
#3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
#4      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
#5      _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
#6      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
#7      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#8      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

i tried removing extra packages and now there is no issue in that still i am giving list of it.

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core:
  firebase_dynamic_links:
  otp_text_field: ^1.1.1
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.1+1
  lottie: ^1.2.1
  country_picker: ^2.0.8
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.7.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.2
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  google_fonts: ^4.0.0
  flutter_colorpicker: ^1.0.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.7
  flutter_font_picker: ^1.2.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.5
  image_cropper: ^3.0.0
  getwidget: ^3.0.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  flutter_image_slideshow: ^0.1.2
  dropdown_button2: ^1.4.0
  flutter_swiper_null_safety: ^1.0.2
  visibility_detector: ^0.3.3
  badges: ^2.0.3
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  share_plus: ^4.0.10
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^20.1.61
  syncfusion_flutter_datagrid: ^20.1.61
  share: ^2.0.4
  decimal: ^2.2.0
  pdf: ^3.8.1
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  geolocator: ^9.0.1
  geocoding: ^2.0.4
  permission_handler: ^10.0.0
  country_currency_pickers: ^2.0.0
  currency_picker: ^2.0.11
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.2
  assets_audio_player: ^3.0.5
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  csc_picker: ^0.2.6
  intl_phone_field: ^3.1.0
  flutter_paypal: ^0.0.8
  audioplayers: ^1.0.1
  flutter_beep: ^1.0.0
  google_geocoding: ^0.2.0
  share_extend: ^2.0.0
  upgrader: ^4.6.1
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+1
  pinch_zoom: ^1.0.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  social_share: ^2.2.1
  csv: ^5.0.1
  firebase_messaging:
  flutter_local_notifications: ^11.0.1
  in_app_review: ^2.0.4
  flutter_html:
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.9.0
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
  linked_scroll_controller: ^0.2.0
  flutter_ringtone_player: ^3.2.0
  location: ^4.4.0
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.1
  flutter_linkify: ^5.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.0
  avatar_glow:
  animator: ^3.0.0
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  lazy_load_scrollview: 1.3.0
  data_table_2: ^2.1.0
  http: ^0.13.4
  flutter_otp_text_field: ^1.1.1
  firebase_analytics:
  get: ^4.6.5
  firebase_auth:
  flutter_toggle_tab: ^1.2.0
  translator: ^0.1.7
  open_street_map_search_and_pick: ^0.1.0
  flutter_calendar_carousel: ^2.0.0
```

Comment: Mobile apps can be killed at any time by the operating system, based upon vendor-chosen algorithms.

Comment: i think i got my problem, actually my app has so many(100+) network image on home page from api with high quality and i have used cached network image so what happens is that those images holds large part of RAM(4 GB) so it gets used 100% and crashes my system. there was no issue in Device with 8 GB RAM

Comment: If you found out the issue by yourself, you should answer to your own question and mark that answer as the right one, so the question will be counted as solved